# Spritekit - terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make boxes, and when you hit the boxes with the bullet, the box you hit, will disappear.

I can make it work, by making a single box in a function. But when Im making a function with a for-loop to create several boxes, the app will crash. When i make the SpriteKitNode variable inside the function, the boxes will be shown correctly, but won't disappear when you hit them with the bullet. Now, Im making the variable outside the function, and the app will crash when i run the project.

```
import SpriteKit

struct PhysicsCategory {
static let Enemy : UInt32 = 1
static let Bullet : UInt32 = 2
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var mainAnimation = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
var squareAnimation = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Squares")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    makeBanners()
    spaceshipPosition()
    makeSquares(numberOfSquaresInRow: 5, numberOfRows: 4, squareRadius: 5, rowSpacing: 40, yStart: 120)
}
```

And the function, where I assume the error is

```
func makeSquares (numberOfSquaresInRow: Int, numberOfRows: Int, squareRadius: CGFloat, rowSpacing: CGFloat, yStart: CGFloat) {

    for rowNumber in 0...(numberOfRows - 1) {
        let squareSpacing = (self.frame.size.width - (CGFloat(numberOfSquaresInRow) * squareRadius * 2)) / CGFloat(numberOfSquaresInRow + 1)

        var extraSpacing = CGFloat(0)
        if rowNumber % 2 == 1 {
            extraSpacing = squareSpacing / 2
        }

        for squareNumber in 0...(numberOfSquaresInRow - 1) {

            squareAnimation.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

            let xPosition : CGFloat = extraSpacing + squareSpacing + squareRadius + (squareRadius * 2 * CGFloat(squareNumber)) + (squareSpacing * CGFloat(squareNumber))

            let yPosition : CGFloat = yStart + (CGFloat(rowNumber) * squareSpacing)

            squareAnimation.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)

            squareAnimation.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: squareRadius)

            squareAnimation.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
            squareAnimation.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bullet

            squareAnimation.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            squareAnimation.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

            self.addChild(squareAnimation)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not all the codes. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1):

Usually , when you meet an error like:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'` it followed by : **reason**.. so you are be able to understand what happened to your project but here I think the problem is that you add too many times the same node with:

```
self.addChild(squareAnimation)
```

so the compiler go to crash because you have just added this node the first time in cycle.

To solve you could add a line immediatly after the FOR cycle to say to compiler "hey , i've a new property, this is my initialization and this happen for each cycle" :

```
let squareAnim = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Squares")
```

and work with the rest of the lines with squareAnim

Comment: When I put the self.addChild(squareAnimation) right after the for-loop, there will be 4 boxes. Better - but there should be 12

Comment: @jonask You weren't suppose to move the addChild outside the for loop, you were suppose to create a new square sprite as the first line of your for loop.  It seems right now squareAnimation is global,  this is very dangerous as you can see by your errors.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Would you make some codes in a comment for me?